# Find colums that contains lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge pandas dataframe 150000 x 330 and I well find columns that have lists `[]`

I have tried

```py
df[['[]' in x for x in df.values]]
```

but it only returns column names.

```
df['FORM_SECTION.CONTRACT.FD_CONTRACT.CONTRACTING_AUTHORITY_INFORMATION.NAME_ADDRESSES_CONTACT_CONTRACT.SPECIFICATIONS_AND_ADDITIONAL_DOCUMENTS.CONTACT_DATA.E_MAILS.E_MAIL'] 

0         [dsfd@inventura.no]
1                        [---@sivingtt.no]
2                                     None
3                                     None
4                                     None
                        ...               
152463                                None
152464                                None
152465                                None
152466                                None
152467                                None
Name: FORM_SECTION.CONTRACT.FD_CONTRACT.CONTRACTING_AUTHORITY_INFORMATION.NAME_ADDRESSES_CONTACT_CONTRACT.SPECIFICATIONS_AND_ADDITIONAL_DOCUMENTS.CONTACT_DATA.E_MAILS.E_MAIL, Length: 152468, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any()
```

### Demo

```
data = {'Col1': [0, 1, 2], 'Col2': [['a', 'b'], ['a'], ['c']], 'Col3': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

   Col1    Col2  Col3
0     0  [a, b]   1.1
1     1     [a]   2.2
2     2     [c]   3.3

df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any()

Col1    False
Col2     True
Col3    False
dtype: bool
```

You can also find the **list of columns with list** as follows:

```
df.columns[df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any()].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['Col2']
```

Comment: df.columns[df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any()].tolist() did give me a list :) tnx

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for the string '[]' in x, not a list.  Try checking for type(x) == list.

I think it would look something like (probably not fully syntactically correct):

```
list_cols = []
for col in df.columns:
         if(any(isinstance(list,x)) for x in df[col]):
              list_cols.append(col)
```

Comment: for i in list_cols:
    print(i) this prints every columns

Answer (score 0):

Consider this dataframe:

```
    a  b   c
0   1  1   1
1   2  2  []
2  []  3   3
3   3  4   4
```

Then to select columns where are `[]`, you can do:

```py
print(df.loc[:, df.apply(lambda x: [] in x.tolist())])
```

Prints:

```
    a   c
0   1   1
1   2  []
2  []   3
3   3   4
```

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, ...]

[152468 rows x 0 columns]

Comment: @BjørnJørgensen Can you please edit your question and put the data there? With correct formatting.

Comment: well, its a big dataframe made from JSON. I get it from a arangodb. df.columns[df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)).any()].tolist() this code did print those colums that have list in it.